# Definition of Phase Locked Loop

Tags: pll

After learning some basics of Phase Locked Loop, I came to a conclusion that it may be defined as a circuit, which in its most basic form, tries to lock(equate) both the phase and the  frequency. But after searching online for a definition, I could not find any definition which resembles mine (explicitly saying that a PLL locks frequency and phase). Wikipedia page also just says

"A phase-locked loop or phase lock loop (PLL) is a control system that generates an output signal whose phase is related to the phase of an input signal."

It doesn't directly say anything about frequency and phase of input and the output being equal. Am I suggesting a wrong general definition? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 7):

As frequency is the rate at which phase changes, locking the phase automatically implies locking the frequency. To state that a PLL locks frequency as well is unnecessary.

The converse is not true, a locked frequency does not imply a consistent phase.